# CDate makes DateAdd formula fail

Tags: sql, ms-access

I hope I will be forgiven for transgressing the rules ever so slightly by asking for a reason, rather than a solution.

I have the following code:

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable (RecordMonth, ...)
SELECT t1.Expr1, ...
FROM
    (   
    SELECT 
        CDate(Format("01-" & Right([t1].[Year-Month],2) & "-" & Left([t1].[Year-Month],4),"dd/mm/yyyy")) AS Expr1, 
        /* ...other fields with no bearing... */
    FROM tcsvMonthData AS t1
    )
WHERE t1.Expr1 >= DateAdd("m",-6,(SELECT MAX(Expr1) FROM t1))
```

`[Year-Month]` in `t1` is a varchar-type field.

This script fails, Access gives the following error message: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

If I remove the `CDate` block the script will work. Happy to have found the answer but I don't understand why the error occurs in the first place. `CDate` constrains a field to a date type. After `format` the field should be a date type already, so `CDate` is redundant, but it should not harm (not in my head, at least). Also, as far as I know `DateAdd` unlike say, `Year`, does not convert the input field to a string, it should maintain a date type. So what is going on here?

EDIT:
`Year-Month` describes the month the record occurred in and it looks like this: `2017-11`. It is a varchar type and the goal is to have it as a proper datetime field in dd/mm/yyyy format where each month is represented by the first day of that month. So May is 01/05/2018 etc.

Comment: _After format the field should be a date type already_ .. No. Format returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seriously overcomplicating this. *CDate* is all you need:

```
CDate([t1].[Year-Month]) AS Expr1
```

**Edit:**

To accept *Null* values, either filter these out, or use *CVDate* to either pass *Null* on:

```
CVDate([t1].[Year-Month]) AS Expr1
```

or supply a default value using *Nz*:

```
Nz(CVDate([t1].[Year-Month]), Date()) AS Expr1
```

Comment: True! Another function that simplifies the whole ordeal is `DateValue` however in one way or another they all fail. Your proposed solution raises the following error message "invalid use of null".
I will check that I didn't make some other mess in experimenting with the solutions that were proposed here but I am starting to suspect that the issue is actually within the `DateAdd` function

Comment: CDate doesn't "fail", but it doesn't accept _Null_ values as input.

Comment: Bingo! `Year-Month` is not supposed to be Null so I din't even think about it but there was indeed one row where the field was null this week. This is very likely what threw off all other attempts as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in sql server please use cdate in place of cast for ms access.

```
 select  cast(format(cast('01-' + left('07/23/2018',2) + '-' + right('07/23/2018',4) as date),'dd/MM/yyyy') as date) AS Expr1
```

change the static date with your column.

Comment: How would this help with MS-Access?

Comment: I do appreciate that you went through the trouble of finding a solution that works for Sql Server, however my question here is not "how do I fix it?" but rather "why does it fail?".
The reason I am asking is to get a better understanding into how Access works so that I can avoid similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It’s been a long time since I have had to use Access but I think the problem isn’t with your use of CDate() but rather the use of Format() on the internal string. Format() needs to operate on a date, but you are giving it a string. Because Format is failing, the surrounding CDate() is failing as well.

You need to use CDate () before Format() like this:

```
        Format(CDate ("01-" & Right([t1].[Year-Month],2) & "-" & Left([t1].[Year-Month],4),"dd/mm/yyyy")) AS Expr1,
```

You may need to do some tweaking to get that to run but the basic idea should work.

The rejected answer below works because Cast As Date (which is functionally equivalent to CDate) is used both before and after Format() so Format() is being passed a Date. The 2nd Cast in that example is redundant.

Comment: I tried but honestly this seems to work the opposite. If I put `CDate` within `Format` then the final result is a string type field and the subsequent `DateAdd` fails as well.
As a small note, I *think* your parenthesis aren't put in the right place. `CDate` should be closed before `"dd/mm/yyyy"`, right?

Comment: Yes, Format() takes a date and returns a String in the specified format. In Access date is stored as a timecode which is not human readable. So with your original example, you take the string date, convert it into a time code, and then use Format() to convert back into a String with a different format. If you are just looking to store the date than you can skip Format() entirely.